# Subscriptions in Paymill

Tags: paymill

A client with a subscription "Large" (recurring payment).

I create a payment and offer object for doing that, and it works.

Now I want to update that subscription to "Small" (a different name and amount) but without updating the credit card.

The paymill flow for doing this is very documented very vague and it's uncertain what the process is.

Have you done anything like this with Paymill, I would be happy to hear about what calls you are doing.

I am using the .NET wrapper

Comment: Why the downvote ? It's a fairly straightforward question, yes ?

Answer (score 1):

To change an offer (plan) of a running subscription there are 3 types you can use.

Here is the documentation: https://developers.paymill.com/en-gb/subscription-v2-workflow/#update-sub-plan

In .NET they are exposed with the three methods, that are documented:

- ChangeOfferKeepCaptureDateAndRefundAsync
- ChangeOfferKeepCaptureDateNoRefundAsync
- ChangeOfferChangeCaptureDateAndRefundAsync

Comment: Hi there thanks for this. our scenario is that we are a new SaaS provider with multiple 'modules', each module essentially being a monthly subscription. The subscriptions can be added at will, with minimum period of one month, but we don't want multiple charge dates for an account. So we want to use a single aggregated offer for the account, and use the ChangeCaptureDateAndRefund method. Do you know how the refunds actually work? Is it that if the user downgrades from 100 to 10EUR half way through the month, the user basically gets 5 month free, or is a 50 refund actually sent to the account ?

Comment: @Sentinel an actual refund will be be performed on the transaction. Of course i recommend to test all the scenarios in test mode before going live. You can use shorter periods, like 2 DAYS for example.

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks a lot. I think maybe a good idea for PayMill would be to just 'not collect' for some users, because Refunds cost the merchant. It depends on the scenario but for PaaS or SaaS type services like what we are building, the user should be able to upgrade and downgrade the total subscription amount flexibly from day to day.